# Center my content- What is The Best Way?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, center

I am trying to figure out the best way to center my content and sidebar on the page. Nothing I've tried is working (I'm very new to CSS & HTML). 
I tried setting the widths to percentages, and set the margin at auto, but something's just not working. I don't want it to have a fixed width because it will look different on different screens. Not sure what the best way to go about this is, any help would be appreciated!
I also tried overflow: auto but that takes away the border-radius on my home page...
http://flashandshine.com/port/?page_id=73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tray this CSS in your container:

```
.container {
   width:80%;
   display:table;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content you're trying to center is a fluid width, you can do some simple math to center it. For example, if your content is 90% wide, there is a remainder of 10% in the parent container, meaning a left and right margin of 5% would center it.

It looks like from your example the problem is that your `<ul>` has padding and margin, and isn't set to a specific width.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I just leared css 2 months ago, and every single time I can't get something centered. You'd think I would remember!

Comment: No worries, happens all the time :)